# ACCESS fails with DATETIME query

Tags: c#, datetime, ms-access

I've a simple query which extract some records according to a DateTime field.
I can't explain why but with some dates it doesn't work (null result).
It seems that it doesn't work with first days of month while it works with last days (10th and above).

[image: Access Table and SQL Query]

In the example above it doesn't work with #04/09/2016# while it works with #09/09/2016#!

Could it depend on Date Format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how can i pass the right day format programmatically (I'm using c#)?
>
> ...
>
> It works formatting the date like this day.toString("MM/dd/yyyy").

If you're using C# then you should **not** be formatting dates as strings to build your query (using *dynamic SQL*). You should be using a *parameterized query* like this:

```cs
var day = new DateTime(2016, 9, 4);
using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Prenotazioni WHERE DataArrivo=?", conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", day);
    using (OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try also this solution.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL view the date is always written `#mm/dd/yyyy#`, even if in the design view it is `#dd/mm/yyyy#`. So your SQL is requesting April 9. Is that your intent ?

Comment: No i try to request September 4th. So how can i pass the right day format programmatically (I'm using c#)?

Comment: Ok solved! It works formatting the date like this day.toString("MM/dd/yyyy"). Thank's